# The specified Checkout Session could not be found

Tags: stripe-payments

**Goal: Create a successful (test) Checkout Session using Stripe's API for checkout.**

[the link for their tutorial on Checkout is here: [https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments]](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments)

I'm creating a checkout session using my UI & building the checkout session with the data supplied to the backend web service using the following code:

```
            var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
            {
                PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                {
                    "card",
                },
                LineItems = stripeCartLineItems,                    
                Mode = "payment",
                SuccessUrl = "https://" + HostName + "/Stripe/OrderPlaced", 
                CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
            };

            var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
            {
                StripeAccount = stripeConnectedAccountId,
                ApiKey = StripeConfiguration.ApiKey
            };

            var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
            Stripe.Checkout.Session session = service.Create(options, requestOptions);

            return Json(new { sessionId = session.Id });
```

As you can see, I receive acknowledgment back from Stripe's API with a valid checkout session id:

[image]

Logs on Stripe's Dashboard confirm a successful checkout session:
[image]

However, I keep getting this error message:
[image]

The API keys have already been refreshed and placed appropriately. That's not the issue... Loading up the test Checkout page is failing. My logs in Stripe's dashboard say this:

[image]

The Javascript call which initiates the redirect to Stripe's checkout experience is copied straight from their tutorial (pasted above). That code looks like this:

```
           checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Stripe/CreateCheckoutSession",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { stripeConnectedAccountId: stripeConnectedAccountId, cartLineItems: scope.cartLineItems },
                }).done(function (resp) {

                    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                        sessionId: resp.sessionId
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                        // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                        // using `result.error.message`.
                        alert(result.error.message);
                    });
                })
```

After going to: https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing. The docs says this for that specific error code: "The ID provided is not valid. Either the resource does not exist, or an ID for a different resource has been provided."

Ok Stripe. Sure sure. You made this API - I'll listen. However, according to your docs, Intellisense, & your sample code... my code is correct and I used the session.Id provided by the response object YOU sent me after initiating a Checkout Session:

[image]

I have no clue how to proceed.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I'm also searching StackOverflow to see if someone has an answer to this. By handling the async webhook, the session is considered completed, so the synchronous checkout session cannot be accessed anymore. Stripe says that the synchronous process cannot be guaranteed but don't we need to use it for the redirect?

Answer (score 3):

If you have already verified the session and keys from server and stripe,
Please check the stripe key used in your client side. The public key used to initialise the stripe in both client & server should be same.

Check the logs in client side to make sure that the key is same.

Comment: Already did. They're fine. That's not it.

Comment: This answer is misleading. In the front you need to have your PUBLIC KEY, in the server side you need to have your SECRET KEY